# Is it possible to create a table with keys in a Rails 2.3.8 migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that I can create a table and then add an index in a Rails 2.3.8 migration, e.g.

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.string :bar
    end
    add_index :foos, :bar
  end
end
```

Can I create a table and specify a key in the CREATE TABLE clause? The migration above generates SQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foos` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `created_at` datetime default NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
    `bar` varchar(255) default NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
ALTER TABLE foos ADD INDEX `index_bar` (`bar`);
```

But what I want is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foos` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `created_at` datetime default NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
    `bar` varchar(255) default NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
     KEY `index_bar` (`bar`)
)
```

I know that this can be done with `#execute`, but it would be so much nicer to use the Rails-y blocks. Can this be done in standard Rails 2.3.8? Using a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the 'execute' command in a Rails migration which takes raw SQL. Your migration might look something like this:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    sql = <<-SQL # This is a "here document"
      CREATE TABLE `foos` (
             `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
             `created_at` datetime default NULL,
             `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
             `bar` varchar(255) default NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
             KEY `index_bar` (`bar`)
      )
    SQL

    execute sql
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :foos
  end
end
```

Comment: I should have specified that I was trying to avoid `#execute`--I'll edit the question. Of course, `#execute` is just what I'm using, but it feels so wrong in Rails to have to fall back to raw SQL for something as trivial as this. :(

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
create_table :foos do |t|
  t.timestamps
  t.index :bar
end
```

Comment: No, I get `undefined method `index' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x5434ce8>`. What version of Rails does this work on? I'm stuck on 2.3.8 for now. :(

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table in comments there are a list of column types

Comment: The API link is *extremely* useful. However, it must be for a newer Rails version than the one I'm running.

Comment: No, it is about 2.3.8 as well, but commenter made a mistake, it seems there is no `index` column type in Rails

Comment: D'oh! Any plugins out there to fill the gap? It seems like such an easy thing to do, and fairly common to want, as well.

Comment: it looks like rails can add index only for exist tables. So it should create table firstly. Also there is documented `index` action that actually doesn`t work. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/index

Comment: I can verify that the create_table index option is invalid. One must first create a table, then add an index to it. So one would need at least two migrations. Hopefully this will be addressed in the next revision of rails.